# tcolorbox as a style

Tags: tcolorbox, expl3

I’m using a `tcolorbox` to mark some keywords. I want to control when these keywords have to be marked. So I created a Boolean variable `\l_style_bool`. The instruction `\bool_set_true:N \l_style_bool` should give

[image]

and the instruction `\bool_set_false:N \l_style_bool` should give

[image]

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
 % Used to apply or not the keyword style
 \bool_new:N \l_style_bool

 % Uncomment this to mark all keywords (1st picture)
 % \bool_set_true:N \l_style_bool

 % Uncomment this to hide the markup around the keywords (2nd picture)
 % \bool_set_true:N \l_style_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~keyword~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\keyword}{ O{green} m O{} }
 { fontupper=\ttfamily,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
 top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
 leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0.3mm,bottomrule=0.3mm,boxsep=0.5mm,
 colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,colupper=red!75!black,#3}{#2}

\begin{document}
 Some text containing a \keyword{keyword}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you meaning to automatically detect when `keyword` is used in the document or is there going to be some markup around each keyword (where the behavior of the markup is determined by the variable)?

Comment: The second one. If the boolean variable is set to true, then all keywords in the text have to be marked.

Comment: `8pt` is not a valid option, by the way.

Comment: @cfr: corrected.

Comment: Note that you cannot have it both ways when the boolean is true. One or other picture must require it be false. See my answer below, though I think the use of expl3 here is rather bizarre, as I say.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I need. I’m trying to be more familiar with `expl3` that’s why I’m using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the case for using `expl3` syntax here. It just seems egregious. However, if you must:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Used to apply or not the keyword style
\bool_new:N \l_style_bool
% Uncomment this to mark all keywords (1st picture)
\bool_set_true:N \l_style_bool
% Uncomment this to hide the markup around the keywords (2nd picture)
\bool_set_false:N \l_style_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \keyword { O{green} m O{} }
{
  \bool_if:NTF \l_style_bool
  {
    \keywordbox [ #1 ] { #2 } { #3 }
  }
  {
    #2
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\keywordbox}{ O{green} m O{} }
{%
  fontupper=\ttfamily,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  left=0mm,
  right=0mm,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0.3mm,
  bottomrule=0.3mm,
  boxsep=0.5mm,
  colback=#1!10!white,
  colframe=#1!50!black,
  colupper=red!75!black,
  #3}{#2}

\begin{document}
 Some text containing a \keyword{keyword}.
\end{document}
```

will give

[image: fancy when true]

in the one case and

[image: plain when false]

in the other.